# Can anyone help me when my left join statement? I think the mySQL Engine is broken

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

Currently I am trying to output thru query the list of **Start_Periods** in a table called **Payslip**. This is just a simple query that I am testing out before turning it into something complex. But at this very simple level, there seems to be something wrong on how mySql Engine is displaying my data.

My current query is

```
   SELECT a.SPERIOD
    FROM Payslip a
    LEFT JOIN Earndetl b ON a.SPERIOD = b.SPERIOD
    LEFT JOIN Ded_detl c ON a.SPERIOD = c.SPERIOD
    WHERE MONTH(a.SPERIOD) = 1
    AND MONTH(b.SPERIOD) = 1
    AND MONTH(c.SPERIOD) = 1
    GROUP BY a.SPERIOD;
```

Which outputs:

```
SPERIOD
2015-01-01
2015-01-16
```

While the following query:

```
SELECT SPERIOD FROM Payslip WHERE MONTH(SPERIOD) = 1 GROUP BY SPERIOD;
```

Outputs:

```
SPERIOD
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-16
2015-01-18
```

Since I am using only Left Join to **EarnDetl** and Ded_detl, regardless if there is the same **SPERIOD** in the two tables, this shouldn't be a problem right? Or is there something wrong with my query that I failed to see for the past hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior! (When in `WHERE`, you get regular inner join result):

```
SELECT a.SPERIOD
FROM Payslip a
LEFT JOIN Earndetl b ON a.SPERIOD = b.SPERIOD AND MONTH(b.SPERIOD) = 1
LEFT JOIN Ded_detl c ON a.SPERIOD = c.SPERIOD AND MONTH(c.SPERIOD) = 1
WHERE MONTH(a.SPERIOD) = 1
GROUP BY a.SPERIOD;
```

If you're not going to select anything else but a.SPERIOD, you can remove the `GROUP BY` and instead do `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Perhaps a bit of explanation wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: @jarlh thank you for your answer, So does this mean that when I left join, all joined tables filters shouldn't be placed in the WHERE Statement?

Comment: @AkiraHora the query first does the WHERE then the JOIN. that's the way SQL Work, first it filters the data then joins it.

Comment: @AkiraHora, Correct! Leave Payslip's condition in WHERE, and put the rest of them in the ON clauses.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks. I'm quite satisfied with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thought id do it with the `with` clause just for a bit of fun.

```
WITH
A as (
    SELECT * FROM Payslip WHERE MONTH(SPERIOD) = 1
),
B as (
    SELECT * FROM Earndetl WHERE MONTH(SPERIOD) = 1
),
C as (
    SELECT * FROM Ded_detl WHERE MONTH(SPERIOD) = 1
)

SELECT a.SPERIOD
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.SPERIOD = B.SPERIOD
LEFT JOIN C ON A.SPERIOD = C.SPERIOD
GROUP BY a.SPERIOD;
```

Comment: This is actually quite interesting, a bit off topic to the question, I am creating this query to place it to Jasper reports, I wonder if I could use this Query despite having multiple statements.

Comment: Actually just noticed you're using MySQL. Not sure if it supports WITH. Im just checking now.

Comment: SQL is such fun, you can acheive the same in so many ways! (E.g. a left join can be done with an inner join unioned with a not exists.)

Comment: @AkiraHora I cant find anything about whether it supports the WITH clause or not. You can just try it and see.

Comment: @CathalMF Thanks for the idea. I'll do my own research on this. ;)